# Angular Reactive Form - Button disabled method called twice

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have simple case that show my question.

`

```
AppComponent.ts
```

`

`

```
 formGroup = new FormGroup({
    firstName:new FormControl(''),
    lastName: new FormControl('')
  });

  isValid(){
    console.log(this.formGroup);
    return true;
    
  }
```

`

`

```
AppComponent.html
```

`

`

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <label>FirstName</label>
    <input [formControlName]="'firstName'" />
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input [formControlName]="'lastName'" />
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!isValid()" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

`

My question is, why I see in the console twice output from isValid method?. Is there any reasone for that?
and will it impact application performance if I use this way with complex form?

note: I woundring why isValid method called twice?

I am excepting the method to be called once.

Comment: Interesting let me know if you found any reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me explain to you. There is a thing in angular called `Change Detection`. This is an internal mechanism inside of `Angular`. This change detection mechanism identified the changes in the `UI`, input, output properties, and value changes in the properties that are binded to different elements on the UI.

So whenever any change is detected in the whole application, then angular runs a `change detection` cycle to update all the properties values along with UI.

Now, let's come to your question. You are calling a function in the template which is `isValid`. So what's happening here is that, whenever any change is detected in the `UI` then angular is running change detection twice while rendering the whole UI that's why you are seeing the `console.log` twice.

**Why is calling change detection twice?**

The answer is, you bind your `formGroup` in the `UI` to the `form` element. So initially, your `formGroup`  is undefined, but later on in your code you are creating a `reactive form`. So when `reactive form` gets created then, then the value of `formGroup` changes from `undefined` to an actual `reactive form` object. So in this way, the value of `formGroup` changes 2 times.

**Will it impact the application's performance?**

Yes, it will impact the application's peformance drastically, that's why it is recommended in angular, not to call functions directly in `html` template. Use properties instead. Please read this as a reference to get more understanding

[Why you shouldn't use functions in the template](https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496#:%7E:text=even%20with%20ChangeDetectionStrategy.-,OnPush%20enabled.,pipe%27s%20input%20does%20not%20change)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Than's expliane alot for me.
I know the change detedction but I don't know the best practice to not use method in template. Also I know that call twice in development mode only to catch it before goes to production :) .

Thank you again my friend